# How to create PHP two column table with values from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want to create a table of names with two columns where names are taken from the database but I don't know how.. I need help.

Names: James, John, Paul, Peter

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con){
echo "Unable to connect DB";
}else{
    $db = mysql_select_db("persons",$con);
    echo "Connected";
}
echo "<table border='1'>";
$count = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_names";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$count++;
    echo "<tr>";
        for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
                echo "<td>{$res['id']}{$res['title']}</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";   
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| James | John  |
+-------+-------+
| Paul  | Peter |
+-------+-------+
```

But my code return:

```
+-------+-------+
| James | Jame  |
+-------+-------+
| John  | John  |
+-------+-------+
| Paul  | Paul  |
+-------+-------+
| Peter | Peter |
+-------+-------+
```

I need your help.

Comment: Do you mean table and not array?

Comment: why would you put James and john in the same row if i may ask? is there a connection between them? you should use tables for presenting lists etc, but if you only want to make a nice layout for the page i'd recommend using <div> instead. you can use float: left and set the width to 50% for example

Comment: @vascowhite: yes sir, it's actually a table not an array

Comment: @galchen: the way the names being arranged is base on their ID's in the database, James is 1, John is 2, Paul is 3 and Peter is 4.

Comment: still, is it just a design thing to put them in the same row? or is there a relation? because if you just want to place them one next to another there's a better way (less html). btw, it has nothing to do with the actual question, but more with the habit of designing correct html pages

Comment: @galchen: nope sir, there is no connection between James and John. Sir, I want/love to learn coding, please let me know the  better way to get actual output, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if there's no relation and the table is used only for layout:

```
echo '<div class="container">';
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo '<div class="item">'.  $res['id'] . $res['title'] . '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

and in css:

```
.container { width: 400px; float: left; }
.container .item { width: 50%; float: left; height: someFixedHeight; }
// or 200px
```

anyways, it's my preference to use tables only for displaying actual tables and avoid using them for layout. you can do anything you want with div's (or in this case you can also use ul and li. Of course it's not a must but normally it requires less HTML and for SEO the html-content ratio is something to consider. if you don't want fixed heights you can wrap each row as with the td/tr examples above.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "<tr>";
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $count++;
    if (!($count % 2)){ echo "</tr><tr>"; }
    echo "<td>{$res['id']}{$res['title']}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Not quite. This will lead to an empty <tr></tr>.

Comment: @str: where did you get that?

Comment: if (1 % 2) in the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

a function

```
function sqlArr($sql){
  $ret = array();
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
  if ($res) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      $ret[] = $row;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

a code

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("persons");
$data = sqlArr("SELECT * FROM tbl_names");
$data = array_chunk($data,2);
```

a template

```
<table border='1'>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
  <tr>
  <? foreach ($row as $cell): ?>
    <td><?=$cell['id']?><?=$cell['title']?></td>
  <? endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: when I test the code , it returns to an error statement: Notice: Undefined variable: cell in C:\wamp\www\tests\rows.php on line 23

Answer (score 0):

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$count++;
    echo "<tr>";
        foreach($res as $val){
                echo "<td>{$val}</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($q)){

    if ($count % 2 == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    echo "<td>{$res['id']}{$res['title']}</td>";

    if ($count % 2 == 0) {
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    $count++;
}
```

edit: I should reload more often.

Comment: sir, though the code returns no error but the output is in 1 column only.