# Creating new table row - PHP while loop

Tags: php, loops, tabular

I am trying to do so whenever my while loop reach each 4 result (4,8,12,16 etc) it will create a new table row.

It should be like this:

```
[table row]
[data] [data] [data] [data]
[/table row]

[table row]
[data] [data] [data] [data]
[/table row]
```

and so on...

Currently I have this:

```
  <?php 
$cat=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kb_categories"); 
        $i = 0;
        while($catData=mysql_fetch_assoc($cat)):
        $i ++; 
        //Select the numbers of articles inside each category.
        $number=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kb_articles WHERE cat_id='".$catData['id']."'"));

        ?>

    <td><img src="/themes/dream/images/icons/folder.gif"><span><?php echo $catData['name']; ?></span> (<?php echo $number; ?>)</td>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Right now, it just generates this:

```
[table row]
[data] [data] [data] [data] [data] [data] etc.
[/table row]
```

I am just not sure how to use the `$i` in this example. Can someone help me?

Comment: **EXACT DUPLICATE** of [How to create php 2 column table with values from the database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299913/how-to-create-php-2-column-table-with-values-from-the-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions I can think of.
Either check when i is equal to for and then insert the row and reset i back to 0.
Or, see if it is exactly divisible by 4 and then insert the row. (Which is probably better because then i will equal the amount of data.)

```
<?php 
$cat=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kb_categories"); 
$i = 0;
while($catData=mysql_fetch_assoc($cat)) :
    $i ++; 
    //Select the numbers of articles inside each category.
    $number=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kb_articles WHERE cat_id='".$catData['id']."'"));

    if($i==3) {
        // Insert row here, probably something like this:
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $i = 0;
    }

?>

<td><img src="/themes/dream/images/icons/folder.gif"><span><?php echo $catData['name']; ?></span> (<?php echo $number; ?>)</td>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Or the second method:

```
<?php 
$cat=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kb_categories"); 
$i = 0;
while($catData=mysql_fetch_assoc($cat)) :
    $i ++; 
    //Select the numbers of articles inside each category.
    $number=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kb_articles WHERE cat_id='".$catData['id']."'"));

    if( (($i+1) % 4) == 0) {
        // Insert row here, probably something like this:
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

?>
<td><img src="/themes/dream/images/icons/folder.gif"><span><?php echo $catData['name']; ?></span> (<?php echo $number; ?>)</td>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used the first method, and I just changed if($i==3) to if($i==5) (since I need 4 records per table row. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- First, get your data into array
- Next, use array_chunk() to split it into several nested arrays
- Finally, in the *template* use 2 nested foreach loops to output
- And, for God's sake, learn to *indent* your code
- **Also, you should NOT count rows by using mysql_num_rows().**
  Use `SELECT count(*)` instead.
- **And there shouldn't be nested queries at all - you should make it with one query using JOIN.** If you have no clue what is it - ask another question here.

Comment: why should you not count rows by using mysql_num_rows() is there something inherently bad about it, or is that just an optimisation?

Comment: Very nice answer, but I think user169691 doesn't exactly have the skills to achieve that, without some more in depth examples, otherwise he wouldn't be asking this kind of question here. You've got to answer people's questions on their own level and let them learn from experience, you can't just chuck them straight in the deep end just because it's not semantically the best way of doing it.

Comment: @user, so, you're always doing stupid thing. If you need only number - ask your database for the number, not for all the rows.

Comment: @Chaim I feel sick from the usual stackoverflow level.

Comment: @Col I quote from your profile "It makes me pain to see extremely unprofessional community and - as a consequence - extremely low quality answers under PHP tag." (i see you are leading by example with your comments), lol

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I tend to disagree with you, There are plenty of quality questions and answers on stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is meant for amatuers and experts alike. If there is someone who doesn't know too much, just guide him gently, or move on - no one will shout at you if you don't answer a question.

Comment: @Chaim there are no experts. Experts just have no spare time to answer zillions exactly the same questions again and again and again, to help people who is as helpless as being unable to do even primitive googling. Only thousands of the alike noobs have spare time to hang here for the whole day and answer "on their own level", unacceptable low one.

Comment: So @Col. Shrapnel is saving the world, one PHP question at a time. Find a different website if you don't like this one.