# Fetching photos in a table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, fetch

I am trying to fetch my mysql data on this way, 5 photos each row, 2 rows max  this seems doesn't work with as the loop keeps to duplicate photos in the 2 rows I have.

Here is my code :

```
    <table border="1" width="%">
<?php
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
                    {

for ($tr=1;$tr<=3;++$tr)
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                for ($td=1;$td<=5;++$td)
                {   


                echo "<td><img width=125 height=125 src=images/".($info['photo']). "></td>";

                }

                echo "</tr>" ;
            }

 }
            ?>

</table>
```

Please help me to solve this, the results keep coming in this status:

[image: results to my current code, how can I stop the duplication]

Comment: another duplicate of [fetching mysql records to a html table using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836291/fetching-mysql-records-to-a-html-table-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...your `while` loop iterates over all photos. For each photo you do 3 * 5 iterations due to your `for` loops. What you actually might want to do is something like this:

```
$column = 0;
$row = 0;
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))  {
    $column++;
    if ($column == 5) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        $column = 1;
        $row++;
    }
    if ($row == 2) {
        break;
    }
    // output your image here
}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to add a limit to the SQL query to fetch no more than `3*5=15` images, i.e. `.. WHERE ... LIMIT 15;`.

Answer (score 1):

following a very easy approach .. first copy the fetched images into a single dimensional array and then place them into the table accordingly

```
while ($ans = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
  $image[] = $ans['photo'];
}
echo '<table>';   
for ($tr = 1; $tr<=2; $tr++) { 
  echo '<tr>';
  for ($td = 1; $td <= 5; $td++) {

    $img = 'images/' . $info[$td*$tr];
    echo '<td><img src="$img" /></td>';
  }
  echo '<tr/>';
}
echo '</table>';
```