# PHP 4 Records per line

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code to show 4 records per line but it shows my code in an absurd manner.  i.e

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l 
.......
```

But my code shows output as. I dont know why i am a new php programmer

```
a b c d
e
f g h i 
j 
k l m n
.......
```

My Code is

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","abc123");
if (!$con)
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mydb", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
echo "<table border='1'>";
$int = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $int++;
   if ($int%5==0)
   {
      echo "<tr>";
   }
   echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
   if ($int%5==0)
   {
      echo "</tr>";
   }
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Thanking in advance

Comment: It is often easier to first create a data structure the way you want (i.e. an array of arrays of 4 elements), and then creating HTML from that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create php 2 column table with values from the database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299913/how-to-create-php-2-column-table-with-values-from-the-database)

Comment: Is one of the answers the solution? If so, please accept

Answer (score 0):

@h_a86:: take a look at the outputed html code. according to your code you dont open the `<tr>` in the first loop. (`int = 0; $int++; ($int==1) != (%5==0)`) just move the $int++ right befor the end of the while

Comment: Hey i cant understand can u elaborate please.

Comment: on your first loop your int counter is set to 1 which will not throw the <tr> in place. either set your int counter to -1 befor the loop or move the int increment just befor the end of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing by 5 instead of 4.
Try

[edit] added complete snippit

```
$int = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   if ($int%4==0)
   {
      echo "<tr>";
   }
   echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
   if ($int%4==0)
   {
      echo "</tr>";
   }
   $int++;
}
```

Comment: Do it for both your if statements ofcourse. If the rest of $int/4 is zero, it will print a <tr> and </tr>. The rest of $int/4 is zero, for $int = 0, 4, 8, 12 etc etc

Comment: By the way, also increment $int at the end, as stated in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

what about this,

```
$int = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

   if ($int%5==0)
   {
      echo "<tr>";
   }
   echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
   if ($int%5==0)
   {
      echo "</tr>";
   }
   $int++;
}
```

just put `$int++` before you close the while

Comment: As stated in my answer, this one is dividing by 5. You want 4, because he only wants 4 cells near each other

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional `if( $int%5 == 0 ){...}` tells your code to wrap a `<TR>` around every 5th record received.  The other records are unaffected.

This behavior produces what you are seeing:

```
<table>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<tr><td>5</td></tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
<tr><td>10</td></tr>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
</table>
```

What you need to do is tell the code to end the last `<TR>` and start a new `<TR>`.

Try something like:

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

$count = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   if ( $count > 0 && $count % 4 == 0 )
   {
      echo "</tr><tr>";
   }
   $count++;

   echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Which should produce:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A Problem. It shows 4 names in each row except 1st row and last row . i.e 3 names in first and last row and 4 in remaining rows