# Alternative to using PHP-GMP to populate two column table

Tags: php

A page is using the PHP GNU Multiple Precision (GMP) to determine how many rows should end up in each column. While the code works, we would like to migrate the application to a new host that does not support the [PHP5-GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) module. That said, what might be the best alternative to generating and populating a two column table that may not always have an even number of results? Further the table design is probably not the best so I am open to alternatives.

The code below taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7302778/666891) gets us close but since it uses `mysql_fetch_array`, it places the items like:

```
a   b
c   d
```

instead of

```
a   c
b   d
```

Is there a way to have it display in the first example?

**Newer code:**

```
<head>
<style>
.container { width: 400px; float: left; }
.container .item { width: 50%; float: left; height: someFixedHeight; }
</style>
</head>
<?php
mysql_select_db("database",$db);
$cat= $_GET["cat"];
echo '<div class="container">';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name WHERE Field4 = '$cat'",$db);
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo '<div class="item">' . $res['Field1'] . '</div>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

**Original code:**

```
<div id="bit-list" align="center" >
<table class="list" width="600" border="0" align="center">
<tr>

<td width="300" height="72" valign="top" border="1">
<div align="left">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name WHERE field4 = '$cat' ",$db);
$myrow3 = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$d3 = gmp_div_q("$num_rows", "2", GMP_ROUND_PLUSINF);
$i = 1;
$result8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name WHERE field4 = '$cat' ",$db);
while ($myrow3 = mysql_fetch_row($result8))
    {
    if ($i <= gmp_strval($d3))
    {
        echo "<p>";
        echo '<a href="detail.php?';
        echo 'page=';
        echo "$myrow3[2]";
        echo '&';
        echo 'pnum=';
        echo "$myrow3[6]";
        echo '">';
        echo "$myrow3[1]";
        echo "</p>";
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
        else
    {
    }
    }
?>
</div></td>

<td width="300" valign="top" border="1">
<div align="left">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name WHERE field4 = '$cat' ",$db);
$myrow3 = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$d4 = gmp_div_q("$num_rows", "2", GMP_ROUND_MINUSINF);
$d3 = gmp_div_q("$num_rows", "2", GMP_ROUND_PLUSINF);
$j = 1;
$result18 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name WHERE field4 = '$cat' ",$db);
while ($myrow3 = mysql_fetch_row($result18))
{
if ($j <= gmp_strval($d3))
{
$j=$j+1;
}
else
{
echo "<p>";
echo '<a href="detail.php?';
echo 'page=';
echo "$myrow3[2]";
echo '&';
echo 'pnum=';
echo "$myrow3[6]";
echo '">';
echo "$myrow3[1]";
echo "</p>";
$j = $j + 1;
}
}
?>

</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i read well, you use `gmp_div_q` for rounding only? Then, you should check [`round()`](http://hu1.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).

The only case, that `round()` cannot cover is `GMP_ROUND_ZERO`, but you don't use that (and you could cover it with a simple `if`).